# Keep values in radio buttons after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, radio-button

I'm building a form with radio buttons.

```
<form id="land" name="input" method="POST" action="test.php">
    <input type="radio" name="Albania" value="Albania" class="test">
    <input type="radio" name="Sweden" value="Sweden" class="test">
    <input type="radio" name="Norway" value="Norway" class="test">
    .....
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="action">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

There are over 150 countries to choose from. And when you choose a country, the application I'm building shows a line chart representing the data for the country in question. I've built a script so that I can have multiple choices. Basically it builds an array of the selected values, and then builds a SQL query from the imploded array.

This works fine when I use the submit button to send the data. But I wanted the chart to update directly when the the user checked a radio button. I added

```
onClick='this.form.submit()'
```

to the input field and this works fine.

My problem is that I can't choose two values now, eg, Norway and Sweden to compare the two, because once I check one radio button the page loads and the value disappears and the radio button is unchecked.

So. How do I send the query without the value disappearing?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: The value will always disappear. The solution is to check the selected values on the new page. You do this by adding `checked="checked"` to the options you want to be checked on page load.

Comment: On succes of ajax call you can take the value from the hidden field and checked that radio button based on that value

Comment: With 150+ countries in the list, I'd consider using a multiline select box or some kind of search mechanism instead.

Comment: Well, I don't now, I think this works pretty good for example: http://www.gapminder.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input <?php if (!(strcmp($_POST['Albania'],"Albania"))) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> type="radio" name="Albania" value="Albania" class="test">
<input <?php if (!(strcmp($_POST['Sweden'],"Sweden"))) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> type="radio" name="Sweden" value="Sweden" class="test">
<input <?php if (!(strcmp($_POST['Norway'],"Norway"))) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> type="radio" name="Norway" value="Norway" class="test">
```

But why don't you use checkboxes instead; maybe the user what to uncheck one of the radio inputs.

I recommend that you change the names of the radio buttons to: `name="country[countryName]"` 
it's easier to retrieve the selected countries by doing `implode()`

```
<input <?php if (in_array("Albania", $_POST['country'])) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> type="radio" name="country[Albania]" value="Albania">
<input <?php if (in_array("Sweden", $_POST['country'])) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> type="radio" name="country[Sweden]" value="Sweden">
<input <?php if (in_array("Norway", $_POST['country'])) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> type="radio" name="country[Norway]" value="Norway">
```

Generate the radio buttons:

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) { ?> 
<input class="className" type="radio" name="country[<?php echo $row['land']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['land'];?>" onClick='this.form.submit()' <?php if (in_array($row['land'], @$_POST['country'])) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> /><?php echo $row['land'];?> 
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Ok, thank's for these insights! The thing is I created the form with a while loop (beacause I thought this more convenient) like this: 
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) { ?>

<input class="1" type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['land']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['land'];?>" onClick='this.form.submit()'   /><?php echo $row['land'];?> <br />

Not quite sure how to implement your solution with the loop? I would prefer not to manually type all 150 input fields.

Comment: give me one minute i will help you

Comment: did you generate your radio buttons only once and used the html into your page or it's generated every time you load that page?

Comment: It's generated every time the page loads

Comment: gr8 then i gave you the solution please try it. but watch out the input names `name="country[]` you can rename it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem. This is just the way HTML and browser work.
If you use an Ajax call instead of submitting the form (and consequently reloading the page), all the options selected will be kept.
If you want the page to be submitted and reloaded so that your server code can be executed you will need to create a server variable or variables that hold(s) the options selected by the user. In the UI, while rendering the form and the radio buttons you will need to check if the option was selected and use the "checked" property, like:

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function ()
        {
            var values = "";
            $('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function ()
            {
                values = values + " - " + $(this).val();
            });
            alert(values);
            // Send your query here..
        });
    });
</script>
```